# How to get Business component instance number from QC/ALM

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-quality-center, hp-uft

I am working on BPT framework on QTP and for a testcase i am using same component multiple times. I want to fetch the Business component instance number from QC ->Testplan->TestCase->Business component. Based on the instance number i will read the required component parameters from excel sheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
Set TestTree = TestSet.TSTestFactory
Set TestList = TestTree.NewList("")

For Each TSTest In TestList

    Set Test = TSTest.Test
    Set objTestFactory = tdc.TestFactory

    Set tFilter = objTestFactory.Filter
    tFilter.Filter("TS_TEST_ID") = Test.ID
    Set tList = objTestFactory.NewList(tFilter.Text)

    Dim objTest
    For Each tst In tList
        If tst.Type = "BUSINESS-PROCESS" Then
        Set objTest = tst
        Exit For
        End If
    Next


    If objTest Is Nothing Then

            Else
        Dim BPTest As BusinessProcess
        Set BPTest = objTest
        BPTest.Load

        ' Get list if component instance from the Test
        Set components = BPTest.BPComponents
        Set Component = components.Item(1)
        For i = 1 To BPTest.BPComponents.Count
            componentName = components.Item(i).Name
            componentInstanceId = components.Item(i).ID
            ComponentId = components.Item(i).Component.ID
        Next
    End if
Next
```

This code will fetch the details from the test lab level and go until the business component level. Currently it is extracting the component name and id. You can modify the code as per your need.

Visit tutorial at [knowlzz](http://knowlzz.com/technology/testing/how-to-get-business-component-from-hp-alm-ota-api/) . It has explained the solution nicely with each and every detail.